# Starred files in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

My starring workflow needs some work. I thought about creating a script to run in drive that looks for starred files (docs, slides, sheets) and adds them to spreadsheet.

I'm a complete noob, so I've checked the script reference to try and find snippets that might work.

```
iterate through drive
if starred file found
  add to new row in spreadsheet
```

```
// Log the name of every starred file in the Designated Spreedsheet.
function addStarred() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //this will need to change to a designated sheet
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();

  while (files.isStarred()) {
    var file = files.next();
    sheet.appendRow(file.getName());
  }
}
```

The ideal would be a list in my spreadsheet that can then be filtered to find the correct starred file.

The first error I see is:

> "Cannot find function isStarred in object FileIterator. (line 6, file "Code")"

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isStarred() is a method of the Class File not of the Class Files. Change the while block to something like the following:

```
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  if (file.isStarred()) sheet.appendRow([file.getName()])
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!! I also want to grab the URL, to save searching ,   if (file.isStarred()) sheet.appendRow([file.getName()],sheet.appendRow([file.getDownloadUrl()]))   It returned an error.

Comment: @PaulRayner: Try `if (file.isStarred()) sheet.appendRow([file.getName(),file.getDo‌​wnloadUrl()]) `

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a curve ball, but this might be a good use case for IFTTT. I looked and they support starred files as a trigger and adding a row to a spreadsheet as an output. You'll have to load the spreadsheet initially since the trigger only fires for new stars.

Comment: Pretty good curve ball. It only works on starred items after the app is turned on. So any existing files won't be added. A good backup, if I can't get this working. Thanks!!!!!!